# Create a dictionary contianing Regexp from file

Tags: python

I have a file that contains something like this:

```
 (стат.{0,4}) (\d+) : $1&#x00A0;$2
 (пункт.{0,3}) (\d+): $1&#x00A0;$2
 (\d+) ((январ|феврал|март|апрел|ма|июн|июл|авг|сентябр|октябр|ноябр|декабр).{0,3}) : $1&#x00A0;$2
```

How can I create a dictionary from this file that will be looking like this? I will need to replace $ with \ in regular expressions, and add r' to key and value in the dictionary,

```
 dic = {r'(стат.{0,4}) (\d+)' : r'\1&#x00A0;\2',
        r'(пункт.{0,3}) (\d+)': r'\1&#x00A0;\2',
        r'(\d+) ((январ|феврал|март|апрел|ма|июн|июл|авг|сентябр|октябр|ноябр|декабр).{0,3})' : r'\1&#x00A0;\2'}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to add the `r`.  That is specific to the python parser telling it to interpret the string as a raw string.  When you read strings from a file, they are "raw" already.

In this case, it's probably as simple as:

```
with open('file') as fin:
    d = {}
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.split(':')
        d[key.strip()] = value.replace('$', '\').strip()
```

Or, perhaps it would be better to open it with `codecs.open`:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('file', 'rb', 'utf-8') as fin:
    ...
```

Comment: What does fin mean here?

Comment: @user3036755 -- It's a file object.  I use `fin` to designate an input data filehandle ... Not sure why that's my standard name, but it is.  When I write data, I use `fout` :)

Comment: key, value = line.split(':')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @user3036755 -- You probably have an empty line at the end of your file or something.  You should be able to check that by adding `if not line.strip(): continue` before you do the `key, value` line.